# AngularJS : how to sort in acsending / decending order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am implementing the table view .In table view I am implementing infinite scroll .In other word I have 2000 objects .I am showing 25 element at one time .When user scroll to bottom it load more 25 elements so on .. I have **"V" or "^"** button on header .On click of this image I want to display in descending order only last 25 elements .when scroll more it load more data  so on ..So I added filter in that but it is not working ..could you please tell me how we can implement this ..

I will give you example :**Like** `A, B,D,C,K,N....T,Z` objects when application load object is load like that .when user click it show **Z,y,X ,W,V,U...A** or again ascending way **"A,B,C...Z"**

here is plunker

```
$scope.setSort = function(idx, reverse){
        $scope.sortval = 'columns['+idx+'].value';
        $scope.reverse = reverse;
    };
```

Html

```
<div class="col col-center brd gray-20" ng-repeat="d in invoice_column_name | filter:{checked: true}">
            <sort-header label="{{d.label}}" index="{{d.index}}" sort-exp="setSort(idx, reverse)"></sort-header>
```

**EDIT**

```
Update
```

I will explain again I have 2000 objects ..It is display randomly .I am display only 25 object at one time .When user scroll more data it show again 25 data..But I want to sort that data in ascending as well as descending way .First I need to sort the 2000 objects then display 25 elements from that and than if user want to load more it scroll data and load that.In your example it is sorting first 25 object only .then load another 25 elements then sort 5o elements ..so on ..so it is not correct solution –
Update plunker

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a large collection of data, then it might be better to load the whole collection first.  I have a couple of reasons for this:

1. Sorting the results on each load operation can be taxing for older browsers, especially as more data is brought in.  This will slow down your UI.
2. If the data is not provided in order by the source, then the process of sorting might scatter the last-loaded set of items over several "pages" of the view *before* the one that your user is looking at. They will then have to search backwards through the results for the new information.

Comment: could you please use plunker

Comment: The problem I've mentioned isn't something that can be sorted out within the app, so a code sample would do you little good. You would need to change the endpoint that you get your data from, and have it do the sorting.

Comment: That depends on your data source, whatever it might be. If you can tell it what order to deliver the data in, and the data isn't likely to change during the user's session, then that's your answer. (The specifics of implementation are down to you.)  If the data can't be sorted by its source, then you will need to download all the records at once to be able to control the sorting with AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Try with with this library https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll 
First you need to load data from server or whatever you like, than in your controller you have to implement one function that gets called when user scrolls down. Also you can order your data in your controller

```
$filter('orderBy')(data, orderProp, desc/asc)
```

see angularjs filter order by. When user clicks on letter you have to order your data and search for first element in the array that starts with that letter. All you have to do next is to implement this in the ngInfinitScroll directive callback function.